# How do I convert a user authenticated with an EmailLink to a user authenticated with Email and Password?

Tags: javascript, firebase, capacitor

I am using the Capacitor-Firebase/authentication plugin in my application.

## My goal

I am trying to turn an Anonymous user into a user with either credentials (email/password).

Also, I want to have his e-mail verified.

## My approach

My approach was to use the EmailLink functionality and then trying to convert it to a user with email and password like the following:

I have successfully signed in a user using the following code from the [docs](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/blob/main/packages/authentication/docs/firebase-js-sdk.md#usage):

```js
const signInWithEmailLink = async () => {
  const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink(email, emailLink);
  const auth = getAuth();
  const result = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
  return result.user;
};
```

Later, I want to convert this to a user with email and password.

I am trying to do this with `FirebaseAuthentication.updatePassword({ newPassword: password.value })`.

## My Problem

This does not work because IMO after using `signInWithCredential` the state of the user is different in the native layer than in the web layer. In the native layer the user is still an Anonymous user so `FirebaseAuthentication.updatePassword()` won't work.

I also tried the following to try to associate a username/password:

```js
const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email.value, password.value)
const auth = getAuth()
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking
linkWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential)
```

This fails with the following error: `auth/provider-already-linked`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution myself:

An EmailLink account is just a flavor account of an Email/Password-Account which does not have a password.

So, if I am in Capacitor, I have to do the following to add the password:

```
const auth = getAuth()
updatePassword(auth.currentUser!, password)
```

On the web, the following command works:

```
FirebaseAuthentication.updatePassword({ newPassword: password })
```